# Clone DAE model with subgroups in three.js

Tags: three.js, collada

I am trying to clone a dae model after loading it. I've tryed several solutions, but I think my problem is that the model has groups inside groups. 
It has a main parent group with all assets. No geometry here.
Its children are one sphere with geometry and 4 more parent groups (no geometry in each one).
Each group has 3 geometries: 2 cones and a cilinder.

I am using the code below, but as you can on the link:
http://caostar.com/3d/PABLOwebgl_loader_collada2.html
The clonned objects does not preserve positions and transformations. Adding the meshes to the new object simply put them all together, as if they all had the same matrix. If you scroll to zoom and make the camera look at inside the weird objects, you gonna see that the sphere and the cones are inside the deformed cilinder.

Any thoughs on how I can achieve the desired effect, having 100 clones and not a hundred deformed 3Dobjects?

This is the code I am using, looping throughout the groups and getting its meshes.

```
var dae;
        var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
        loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
        loader.load( './models/collada/caostar/estrela4.dae', function ( collada ) {

            dae = collada.scene;
            dae.scale.set(16,16,16);

            var piece = collada.scene.children[0];

            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                var newPiece = new THREE.Object3D();

                //looping through the groups. If a group has children, loop again
                for (var j = 0; j < piece.children.length; j++) {
                    if(piece.children[j].children.length > 0){
                        for (var j2 = 0; j2 < piece.children[j].children.length; j2++) {
                            var newMesh = new THREE.Mesh(piece.children[j].children[j2].geometry, piece.children[j].children[j2].material);
                            //this applyMatrix doesnt do anything :/
                            if( piece.children[j].children[j2].geometry.matrix )newMesh.geometry.applyMatrix( piece.children[j].children[j2].geometry.matrix );
                            newPiece.add(newMesh);
                        }
                    }else{
                        var newMesh = new THREE.Mesh(piece.children[j].geometry, piece.children[j].material);
                        //this applyMatrix doesnt do anything :/
                        if(piece.children[j].geometry.matrix)newMesh.geometry.applyMatrix( piece.children[j].geometry.matrix );

                        newPiece.add(newMesh);
                    }
                }

                newPiece.position.set(Math.random()*10-5,Math.random()*10-5,Math.random()*10-5);
                //newPiece.scale.set(sizes,sizes,sizes);
                newPiece.updateMatrix();
                scene.add( newPiece );

            }


        } );
```

///////UPDATE

Ok, I've found the solution for my specific problem but, couldnt figure it out how to properly clone a collada with any kind of subgroups.

Here is my code. Hope it can help someone.

```
    var dae;
    var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
    loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
    loader.load( './models/collada/caostar/estrela4.dae', function ( collada ) {

        dae = collada.scene;
        dae.scale.set(16,16,16);
            var piece = collada.scene.children[0];
            //
            //I will keep the parent names to avoid meshe being added twice
            var parentsNames = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                var newPiece = new THREE.Object3D();
                piece.traverse( function ( child ) {

                    //check if child has children but exclude the main group. This is custom part and must be addpted for each DAE to be clonned
                    if(child.children.length > 0 && child.children.length < 5){

                        //create the group
                        var newPieceChildren = new THREE.Object3D();
                        //
                        parentsNames.push(child.name);
                        //
                        child.traverse( function ( child ) {
                            var newMesh = new THREE.Mesh(child.geometry, child.material);
                            //this will apply all transformations to the piece
                            newMesh.applyMatrix( child.matrix)
                            newPieceChildren.add(newMesh);

                        });
                        //this will apply all transformations to the group
                        newPieceChildren.applyMatrix( child.matrix);
                        newPiece.add(newPieceChildren);

                    //se if it is an isolated child with no children and if it has not been included in the subgroups
                    }else if(child.children.length == 0 && parentsNames.indexOf(child.parent.name) == -1){
                        var newMesh = new THREE.Mesh(child.geometry, child.material);
                        //this will apply all transformations to the piece
                        newMesh.applyMatrix( child.matrix)
                        newPiece.add(newMesh);
                    }

                } );
                //
                scene.add(newPiece);
            }

            });
```